# Custom Brush with Undo/Redo operation in Android Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap, android-paint

I want to implement a canvas drawing application with custom brush & undo/redo operation. First of all my code works perfectly without using the custom brush (including the undo/redo operation). According to this answer [How to make custom brush for canvas in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428874/how-to-make-custom-brush-for-canvas-in-android) I used simple image spikes for bitmap draw.

[image]

Now the issue are,

1. The undo, redo operation doesn't works, custom brush paints over and over again whenever moving the touch points.

   Q: How to make the undo/redo operation work?
2. The custom brush stokers aren't smooth as they should. Right now they looks rough and artificial.

   Q. How to make the painting smooth and natural with custom brush strokes?

[image]

Check my sample code here,

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

    private Context ctx;

    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    private Map<Path, Float> brushMap = new HashMap<Path, Float>();
    private Map<Path, List<Vector2>> customBrushMap = new HashMap<Path, List<Vector2>>();
    
    private Bitmap mBitmapBrush;
    private Vector2 mBitmapBrushDimensions;
    private List<Vector2> mPositions = new ArrayList<Vector2>(100);
    private boolean isCustomBrush = false;

    private int selectedColor;
    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private Path drawPath;
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000, paintAlpha = 255;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

    private static final class Vector2 {
        public Vector2(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public final float x;
        public final float y;
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ctx = context;
        setupDrawing();
    }

    private void setupDrawing() {
        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;

        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setDither(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        drawPath.reset();
        drawPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            drawPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        customBrushMap.put(drawPath, mPositions);
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        drawPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        paths.add(drawPath);
        brushMap.put(drawPath, brushSize);
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPath.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {
        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        //detect user touch
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                if (isCustomBrush) {
                mPositions.add(new Vector2(x - mBitmapBrushDimensions.x / 2, y - mBitmapBrushDimensions.y / 2));
                }
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        for (Path p : paths) {

        drawPaint.setColor(colorsMap.get(p));
        drawPaint.setShader(shaderMap.get(p));
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushMap.get(p));
        drawPaint.setAlpha(opacityMap.get(p));

        if (isCustomBrush) {
            if (customBrushMap.get(p) != null) {
                for (Vector2 pos : customBrushMap.get(p)) {
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    ColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(selectedColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                    paint.setColorFilter(filter);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, pos.x, pos.y, paint);
                }
            }
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(p, drawPaint);
            drawPaint.setColor(selectedColor);
            drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
            canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        }
    }
        canvas.restore();
    }

    public void setCustomBrush(Activity activity, String customBrush) {
        isCustomBrush = true;
        invalidate();
        int patternID = getResources().getIdentifier(customBrush, "drawable", "com.androidapp.drawingstutorial");
        mBitmapBrush = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), patternID);
        mBitmapBrushDimensions = new Vector2(mBitmapBrush.getWidth(), mBitmapBrush.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To make your brush look "smoother" not 100% sure what is meant by that, but you would need to tighten up the dots on the image you are using for your custom brush. Making them more compact will make the edges look smoother.

As for undo redo, in your touchUp method your never adding to customBrushMap only brushMap. So in the ondraw there is nothing to draw since that map will always be empty.

Comment: Inside the onDraw() the for (Vector2 pos : customBrushMap.get(p)) {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, pos.x, pos.y, null);
                    } loop overwrites the path again, making the path drawing twice. How can I draw the path just once? Without the loop it's not possible to get the x & y co-ordinates from the verctor2 list.

Comment: The only  thing I see is that in your else you're calling drawPath twice.

Comment: Could you please run the code once to check the issue I'm talking about?