# how to draw brushes or shape using path when moving finger fast in andorid canvas (generate missing point when user move finger fast)

Tags: android, canvas, path, touch-event

Im really confuse that how can i draw professional brushes in android, im drawing circle using path when user moves its finger on screen but when user move its finger slow the number of circle increase and when user move finger fast the number of circle is very less, suppose user moves it finger very fast ther will be only 6 7 circle on that path but if user moves it finger slowly ther will be 30/40 or more circle on the path, which seems very  buggy, is this is possible that moveing finger fast stores less points? but if i talk about line , the line on canvas draw prefectly while user moves it finger fast or slow, im sharing my code below

```
    private void DrawCircleBrush(List<PointF> points) {
    PointF p1 = points.get(0);
    PointF p2 = points.get(1);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);

    for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
        int rc = (int) (20 +(this.paintStrokeWidth/5));
        path.addCircle(p1.x, p1.y, (float) rc, Path.Direction.CCW);
    }

    this.invalidate();

}
```

I call DrawCircleBrush Fucnion on action_move like this

```
path.reset();
points.add(new PointF(x, y));
DrawCircleBrush(points);
```

You can see the difference of fast moving and slow moving finger in attached picture.

[image: here is the difference of fast moving finger and slow moving finger]

What i want to Achive you can see in this photo, as the brush draw same in this app when i move finger fast or slow,

[image: This is what i want to achive]

Comment: Yes that is common, and not only in android, you reproduce the same on HTML canvas when moving the mouse very fast, in a line you probably do not notice because there is a continuous segment between points creating the illusion of a perfect draw

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yes i came to know when moving finger fast we lost some touch points, but the line or free path always perfect because line join its first point to last point,  check this https://gist.github.com/rajib010/fb707ff115396a723662542aea43138e this man help me out by joing my brush first point to last ,, but there is only a bit problem there when moving finger fast the brush got more thick due to more points, now what i want is if we move finger fast or slow the number of point sould always be same,

Comment: `move finger fast or slow the number of points should always be the same`, that highly depends on the hardware, an idea you can research is to do some "post-processing" to add or remove points to match as many as you need

Comment: @HelderSepulveda im really stuck at this point, i would love if you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok At last i find solution.
this is how im getting all the points , note that this a theorem called Bresenham's line algorithm and its only works with integer,
this is how im getting all the point , move finger fast or slow point will always be same :D

```
//x0,y0 , is the starting point and x1,y1 are current points

public List<PointF> findLine( int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    List<PointF> line = new ArrayList<PointF>();

    int dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0);
    int dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0);

    int sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
    int sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;

    int err = dx-dy;
    int e2;

    while (true)
    {

        line.add(new PointF(x0,y0));

        if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1)
            break;

        e2 = 2 * err;
        if (e2 > -dy)
        {
            err = err - dy;
            x0 = x0 + sx;
        }

        if (e2 < dx)
        {
            err = err + dx;
            y0 = y0 + sy;
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

How im using this function for my brush,

```
             //radius of circle
            int rc = (int) (20 +(this.paintStrokeWidth/5));
            //getting the points of line
            List<PointF> pointFC =findLine((int)this.startX,(int) this.startY,(int) x, 
            (int) y);
            //setting the index of first point
            int p1 = 0;
            //will check if change occur
            boolean change = false;

            for(int l=1; l<pointFC.size(); l++){

                //getting distance between two pints 
                float d = distanceBetween(pointFC.get(p1),pointFC.get(l));
                if(d>rc){
                    // we will add this point for draw
                    //point is a list of PointF //declared universally
                    points.add(new PointF(pointFC.get(l).x,pointFC.get(l).y));
                    we will change the index of last point
                    p1 = l-1;
                    change = true;

                }
            }
            if(points.size() >0){
                path.reset();
                DrawCircleBrush(points);
            }

            if(change){
                we will cahnge the starts points, //set them as last drawn points
                this.startX = points.get(points.size()-1).x;
                this.startY = points.get(points.size()-1).y;
            }

   //Distance betwenn points
   private float distanceBetween(PointF point1,PointF point2) {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2) +  
        Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2));
    }

//this is how im drawing my circle brush
private void DrawCircleBrush(List<PointF> points) {

        Path path = this.getCurrentPath();
        path.moveTo(points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y);

        for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
            PointF pf = points.get(i);
            int rc = (int) (20 +(this.paintStrokeWidth/5));
            path.addCircle(pf.x, pf.y, (float) rc, Path.Direction.CCW);

        }
    }
```

Result: brush is same even move finger fast or slow  [image: Moving finger fast or slow no difference]

Answer (score 1):

Check the "colored_pixels" from [here](https://gist.github.com/rajib010/fb707ff115396a723662542aea43138e)

Comment: I used this but it didnot solve my problem, this code is  just connecting the last point to current point which is not what i wan, i want all the missing points when user move finger fast, and point should always be same no matter what every the speed of moving finger is, and i solved it, you can see my answer ,

Comment: I again tried to do the same there but your solution is perfect.

Comment: im not good at brushes! need your help ,i tried but i couldnot make the brush perfect , and you are very good at this, i want this brush , http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques ( Pattern-based brushes)

Comment: Make a new question regarding this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789906/how-to-create-custom-brushes-in-android please answer here

Comment: im waiting for your response bro ! ? i have shared the question link in previous comment.