# How to Create Custom brushes in Android

Tags: android, canvas, paint, brush

I have created some brushes but i need more and i found some brushes in JS but i couldn't convert them perfectly in android code, This is the Link http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/  can some covert these brushes from JS to Andorid code, I have tried different approaches to make these brush works but most of them are still improper ,
i also want some of brushes from this app , https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsk.sketchbook&hl=en

i converted Sliced" strokes this one from the link and it works fine but im unable to do so with others

```
private void multistrokePen(float x, float y, Path path) {

        path.moveTo(this.startX, this.startY);
        path.lineTo(x, y);

        path.moveTo(this.startX- (this.paintStrokeWidth/2), this.startY - (this.paintStrokeWidth/2));
        path.lineTo(x - (this.paintStrokeWidth/2), y - (this.paintStrokeWidth/2));

        path.moveTo(this.startX- (this.paintStrokeWidth/4), this.startY - (this.paintStrokeWidth/4));
        path.lineTo(x- (this.paintStrokeWidth/4), y - (this.paintStrokeWidth/4));

        path.moveTo(startX+ (this.paintStrokeWidth/4), startY + (this.paintStrokeWidth/4));
        path.lineTo(x + (this.paintStrokeWidth/4), y + (this.paintStrokeWidth/4));


        path.moveTo(this.startX + (this.paintStrokeWidth/2), this.startY + 
         (this.paintStrokeWidth/2));
        path.lineTo(x + (this.paintStrokeWidth/2), y + (this.paintStrokeWidth/2));

        startX =x;
        startY =y;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I converted some of those. [See here](https://gist.github.com/rajib010/fb707ff115396a723662542aea43138e). See "lines_pattern" to understand how you should use those in structured way.

Comment: nice work! and do you know how to make a cap of a path just like a pen ? in andorid they are only few caps if you can check this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsk.sketchbook&hl=en they are making different brushes very prefcetly, and some how i solved my problem of smooth path but still not able to create a cap like them , in some brushes they have a cap just like real pen like from the start and end of path the cap is like arrow .

Comment: Cap of a path means?

Comment: check my path they start and end is like a circle, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J58HXMKjBVxMKCAtvRkiK9sxl4Iqw4aT/view?usp=sharing
 And check the path in this app, their starting and ending are like an arrow a real pen https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zpMvWx_bWSiLTPPCdHHxUAo46HfTEYru/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.