# Android Custom Brush Colors

Tags: java, android, graphic, brush, colormatrixfilter

I'm trying to make custom brushes for my Android painting app. I started with Michael's code ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428874/how-to-make-custom-brush-for-canvas-in-android/8700065#8700065)) and I have managed to get .png brushes and use that as a bitmap and redraw it. It works fine but I can't change the colour. Tried using the `setcolorfilter` and `colormatrixfilter` but it doesn't seem to be working. Anyone knows how I can do this?

```
private Bitmap mBitmapBrush;
   private Vector2 mBitmapBrushDimensions;
   private List<Vector2> mPositions = new ArrayList<Vector2>(100);
private Paint mPanit;


    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapBrush = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(),R.drawable.brush1);
        mBitmapBrushDimensions = new Vector2(mBitmapBrush.getWidth(), mBitmapBrush.getHeight());

    }

 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        for (Vector2 pos : mPositions) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, pos.a, pos.b, mPanit);

        }



    invalidate();
    }
```

When I tried using the Colormatrixfilter, the .set function was giving an error.

Comment: Here the example is given for ColorPicker: http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-cutomized-color-picker-in.html

Comment: What is error? Can we see your attempts to use `ColourMatrixFilter` and `setColourFilter`? Also you don't appear to be assigning anything to `mPanit`, if you don't so this, then you could be seeing `NullPointerException`

Comment: Sorted the error, is working fine now, had forgotten the ColorMatrixColorFilter. I have a another problem now. Is there any way i can paint my .png image as a "path" to get a smother brush effect. the faster i dragg my finger i miss pixels

Comment: Obviously copied from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428874/how-to-make-custom-brush-for-canvas-in-android/8700065#8700065

Comment: @Michael So what? If you post code on here, you should expect it will be copied. Why else would you post it?

Comment: @westen That you might learn from it. Copy-And-Paste programming is not desired.

Comment: @Michael: as the line at the bottom of every page states, the stuff we post here is licensed under [a Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that allows anyone to copy it *as long as they attribute the author* - if you find someone copying your stuff without linking to the place where they got it, please just flag it for moderator attention or use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In order to change the bitmap color you need to add color to your paint object and apply it into bitmap. See the working example here,

```
  for (Vector2 pos : customBrushMap.get(p)) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(R.Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        paint.setColorFilter(filter);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, pos.x, pos.y, paint);
}
```

Result,

[image]